# Reg Ex to match host name - different lenghts

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex to give just the `hostname` from a `FQDN`.

E.g. I want just "`host`" from "`host.company.com`".

I've come up with this so far:

```
^(.{4}).*
```

However, because some devices stored in the CMDB dont have the full FQDN, it can also catch devices with no dot.

What I am struggling now with is when the hostname has different lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So since we are trying to get everything before the first period we do:

```
^(.*?)\.
```

The question mark indicates to match as little as possible and we escape the . to have it represent an actual dot.

Which returns "host" when matched against host.company.com.

To account for the fact that there may not be a period we use the `|` modifier.

```
^(.*?)(\.|$)
```

Where $ will match the end of the line.

However if your not sure whether you need a period or not, I would say to not use a regex, instead use a find function or algorithm on the string, this will be more practical and robust.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but I realise the side issue now: /n These device names are stored in a CMDB, but not all are stored as FQDN. So thats why I modified my initial regex to be: ^(.{4}).* which then can match even if there is no dot, e.g. the string will just be "host"

Comment: Alright, You'll still run into the same problem if the host is more than 4 letters though

Comment: Updated answer for new constraints

Comment: Hi @jozefg, thanks for your help. I'm searching on another attribute in the CMDB, and your regex does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
^([^.]+)(\.|$| )
```

Should capture it (and I'm using it this way, as it provides a non-greedy regex supported by most implementations).

Comment: Actually just `^([^.]*)` should suffice, and be portable to pretty much any regex implementation with capturing parentheses.